# Which has priority, the form tag an input is in or the form attribute of the input?

Tags: html, forms, input

In this example:

```
<form id="form2"></form>
<form id="form1">
    <button type="submit" form="form2">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Which form will the button belong to? Does the button tag being inside the `form1` tag override the `form` attribute of the button, or is it the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful experimentation shows that `form` attribute has priority, i.e. if you click the button `form2` will be submitted.

Here is example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbxrwu0p/

Following code (from the fiddle) can demonstrate the effect:

```html
<form action="https://www.ibm.com" id="form2"></form>
<form action="https://www.amd.com" id="form1">
    <button type="submit" form="form2">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

When you click button https://www.ibm.com is loaded.

Also, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes_common_to_all_input_types) says:

> `form` The id of the  of which the input is a member; if absent, the input is a member of the nearest containing form, or is not a member of a form at all